# Reflection problems with super class in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

My goal is to create class level annotations, but I keep getting this error. For some reason, reflection isn't working when I use getClass to get the information of the annotation. I tried using aspects, but I'm not sure how to make spring boot aspect annotations class level.

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Class.
```

Below are the classes I used

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ValidateInput {
    short minLength();
    short maxLength();
    String regex() default ""; 
}
```

```
public abstract class SimpleValidation {

    private String text;
    private ValidateInput info = this.getClass().getAnnotation(ValidateInput.class);

    protected SimpleValidation(String text) {
        this.text = text;   
    }
}
```

```
@Value
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ValidateInput(maxLength = 50, minLength = 5, regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$")
public class Email extends SimpleValidation {
    String email;

    public Email(String email) {
        super(email);
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to recreate the Bean validation behaviour which is already something standard, [try to use it](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation), as it will be easier than creating a heavy hierarchy of classes for achieving that.

Spring will be able to verify your validation automatically (After deserializing a JSON body, before inserting in DB..)